# D3.js manually creating a diverging color scale? Newbie here

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a visualization, and I'm really getting tripped up on the color scale part. It's kind of laughable how confused this is making me, but lets chalk it up to me being a huge d3 newb...

```
var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([-850, -500, -25, 0, 25, 500, 2100])
            .range(["blue", "lightblue", "grey", "white", "grey", "pink", "red"]);
          var labels = ["-850 - -500", '-499 - -25','-24 - 25', '26 - 500', '501 - 2,100'];
```

Basically I just want to make a range where (-850 to -500) fills the polygon with blue, (-499 to -25) fills with light blue, (-25 to -1) fills with grey, (0) fills with white, (1-25) grey... so on and so forth. I don't want to have colors in between these discrete seven ranges, so scaleLinear is probably wrong--but I think there's a lot wrong here.

I'm not familiar with the different d3.scaleXXX variations, but I have experimented with a few and I'm coming up empty handed. I'm not sure if it's because I'm not using the proper d3.scale function, or if my code/ranges are wonky... Or perhaps a combination of both. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [threshold scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#threshold-scales), which maps values to a *discrete* range, and map subsets of the domain to these discrete values:

```
colorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
            .domain([-850, -500, -25, 0, 25, 500, 2100])
            .range(["none", "blue", "lightblue", "grey", "white", "grey", "pink", "red"]);
```

Because of how `scaleThreshold()` works, you need one more value in the range than in your domain to achieve the expected effect. Think of the domain as the thresholds and the range as the values:

```
none | blue | lightblue | grey | white | grey | pink | red
   -850   -500         -25     0       25    500    2100
```

In the same vein, you can also use a threshold scale for your labels:

```
labelScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
                .domain([-850, -500, -25, 25, 500, 2100])
                .range([">850", "-850 - -500", '-499 - -25', '-24 - 25', '26 - 500', '501 - 2,100', '>2,100']);
// labelScale(1000) == '501 - 2,100'
```